# How do I read a property from Project.properties or local.properties?

Tags: android, properties

Sorry to ask what seems like such a basic question, but I've had no luck finding this information.  I want to read settings out of the Android project properties files (project.properties or local.properties) and I'm having no luck.  System.getProperty seems to be of no use, always returning null.

Comment: Use SharedPreferences instead.:-)

Answer (score 2):

1 Create a file named subtype.properties in assets folder of your android project

2 edit the file for key-value -

```
 key=value
 url=www.xyz.com
 .....
```

Now Call this in Your activity -

```
 Properties prop = new Properties(); 
 try {
    prop = loadPropties();
 } catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Exception", e);
 }

 Log.d(TAG,"The value in prop file is " + prop.getProperty("key"));



//Write this function in your activity -

private Properties loadPropties() throws IOException {
    String[] fileList = { "subtype.properties" };
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    for (int i = fileList.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    String file = fileList[i];
    try {
      InputStream fileStream = getAssets().open(file);
      prop.load(fileStream);
      fileStream.close();
      }  catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e(TAG , "Got exception " + e);
     }
  }
  return prop;
 }
```